# Laravel Sactum and Fortify - How to use them both?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-sanctum, laravel-fortify

Im working with Laravel 8 Project I have installed. Jetstream, Fortify, Sanctum, etc..

Now I need to made an app in html and jquery to the user login via API
and the made some processes within from the API

But I cannot understand how to make it.
Where Can i create the user token when he logins.. or if it's good to point my html login to /login of the Fortify Package.

I didn't found anythiing about this on the net.. please if someone made use of it... I will apreciate !

Comment: Have you read through the [Jetstream documentation](https://jetstream.laravel.com/1.x/introduction.html)? There is an [entire section](https://jetstream.laravel.com/1.x/features/api.html) on how to use it with APIs.

Comment: I dont want to users have the ability to create tokens... I need only one token per user for a login and for a process. thats all.